# How to resize UIImageView after loading image from URL w/ Kingfisher

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, kingfisher

I would like to resize any downloaded images so they maintain their aspect ratio, however are all as wide as the `UITableViewCell` they are rendered in.

My UIImageView is configured with the `contentMode` as `AspectFit` and I have the following anchors on my cell:

[image]

I am almost there with the current attempt:

```
class AnimatedImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var gifView: AnimatedImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var refreshCell: (() -> Void)?

    func render(imageUrl: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: imageUrl) else { return }

        gifView.kf.setImage(with: url) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                let ratio = value.image.size.width / value.image.size.height
                let newHeight = self.gifView.frame.width / ratio
                self.imageHeightAnchor.constant = newHeight
                self.refreshCell?()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error) // The error happens
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also:

```
class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {

    let images = [
        "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*OJxJTJLSyqJ0nMeuswuCSQ.gif",
        "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/552a5cc4e4b059a56a050501/565f6b57e4b0d9b44ab87107/566024f5e4b0354e5b79dd24/1449141991793/NYCGifathon12.gif",
        "https://media2.giphy.com/avatars/100soft/WahNEDdlGjRZ.gif"
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.allowsSelection = false

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "AnimatedImageTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let imagePath = images[indexPath.item]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! AnimatedImageTableViewCell

        cell.refreshCell = {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }

        cell.render(imageUrl: imagePath)

        return cell
    }
}
```

However in some case the cell is too tall. The images renders full width, with the correct aspect ratio, there is just way too much space above and below the image.

I also get errors in the console as follows:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000329770 Kingfisher.AnimatedImageView:0x7fd339e19330.height == 268.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000032a8f0 Kingfisher.AnimatedImageView:0x7fd339e19330.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd339e1a280.topMargin + 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000032a850 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd339e1a280.bottomMargin == Kingfisher.AnimatedImageView:0x7fd339e19330.bottom + 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000032a7b0 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600001908ee0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd339e1a280 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000323980 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd339e1a280.height == 450.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000032a6c0 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600001908ee0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fd339e1a280 )>"
)
```

[image]

Comment: which kingFisher version number you use ?

Comment: Hey, I am using version 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply try to resize the image view after setting its `image` property. For example:

```swift
class ResizableImageView: UIImageView {

  override var image: UIImage? {
    didSet {
      guard let image = image else { return }

      let resizeConstraints = [
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image.size.height),
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: image.size.width)
      ]

      if superview != nil {
        addConstraints(resizeConstraints)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, add its normal constraints omitting `heightAnchor` and `widthAnchor` ones, because those will be added as soon as the image gets added (I'd recommend not using interface builder at this point):

```swift
let imageView = ResizableImageView(frame: .zero)
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(imageView)

// These are only illustrative constraints
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

imageView.image = image
```

Here's a complete and fully functional example:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    downloadImage(
      fromURL: URL(string: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F33105753%2F184176199496%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&rect=0%2C0%2C400%2C200&s=a92a5a03c153d312d682b2dfedd6a6ad")!,
      completionHandler: { [weak self] image in
        guard let self = self, let image = image else { return }

        let imageView = ResizableImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        imageView.image = image
      })
  }

  func downloadImage(fromURL url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

    operationQueue.addOperation {
      guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
          completionHandler(nil)
        }

        return
      }

      OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        completionHandler(image)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to recreate your project with provided code and everything worked as expected until I noticed that your image view is constrained to cell content view margins. Then it started to throw those layout errors and the cells became unreasonably high. So my guess is that you need to make sure your image view constraints are not relative to cell margins.

[image: margins]
[image: constraints]

Also make sure that you do not have `heightForRowAt` override in your view controller.

To completely get rid of the autolayout errors you can set the bottom constraint priority to 999 ([blog post](http://aplus.rs/2017/one-solution-for-90pct-auto-layout/) with explanation about why priority helps)